# Why my setTimeout doesn't work with recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

I'm just wondering why my `setTimeout` doesn't work in recursive pattern. It ran for just twice and stopped.

Here's the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/vp90c10s/

```
var amqp = function() {
    return {
    connect: function(url, callback) {
        callback();

    }
  }
}

var module = {
    connect: function() {
        var self = this;    
    amqp().connect('', function() {
        console.log('trying to connect');
        setTimeout(self.connect, 1000)
    })
  }
}

module.connect();
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will call the given function just fine, but not in the context of your `module` object, so it will fail to access `self.connect` the second time.

Comment: Anyway I can fix this?

Comment: See the linked duplicate and also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)